# Is there any way to reduce the CPU consumption of GStreamer streaming？

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I use GStreamer to implement RTMP streaming, and the CPU usage is as high as 400%. Is there any way to reduce the CPU usage?

The main function of the code is to continuously receive the mat image of OpenCV, put it into appsrc, and finally push the RTMP stream

The code is as follows：

```
void cb_need_data(GstElement *appsrc, guint unused_size, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("need data!\n");
    static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    guint size;
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    GstMapInfo map;

    size = 700 * 700 * 3;
    buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, size, NULL);

    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

    while (image.data == NULL)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    };
    memcpy(map.data, image.data, size);

    GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer) = timestamp;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 30);
    timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer);

    g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
    gst_buffer_unref(buffer);
    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
    {
        /* something wrong, stop pushing */
        g_main_loop_quit(loop);
    }
}

void *rtmpPush(void *p)
{
    /* init GStreamer */
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);
    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *conv, *x264enc, *h264parse, *flvmux, *videosink;
    /* setup pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
    appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "source");
    conv = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "conv");
    h264parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "h264parse");
    flvmux = gst_element_factory_make("flvmux", "flvmux");
    x264enc = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "x264enc");
    videosink = gst_element_factory_make("rtmpsink", "videosink");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(videosink), "location", "rtmp://218.77.60.210:1935/rtmplive/354", NULL);
    /* setup */
    // g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc),
    //              "stream-type", 0,
    //              "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc),
                 "is-live", 1,
                 "stream-type", 0,
                 //"format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL,
                 "caps",
                 gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                                     "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "BGR",
                                     "width", G_TYPE_INT, 700,
                                     "height", G_TYPE_INT, 700,
                                     "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,

                                     NULL),
                 NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc, conv, x264enc, flvmux, videosink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many(appsrc, conv, x264enc, flvmux, videosink, NULL);

    g_signal_connect(appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(cb_need_data), NULL);
    //g_signal_connect(appsrc, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(cb_enough_data), NULL);
    /* play */
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    /* clean up */
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(INT_MAX);
    }
}
```

Is there any other plugin that can replace the existing plugin and reduce CPU usage?
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: According to my limited knowledges on another library FFmpeg, most of CPU is mainly consumed by video encoding stuffs inside the library, and maybe not user-side code. Such a video processing library/binary may try making use of every CPU core by default, and configurable via some parameters.

Comment: tks，i will try this

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I comment out the code line by line to test, I found that it's `gst_buffer_unmap` that cause the high cpu load, in my case.